# Javascript - write links to new tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, hyperlink

Using Javascript in a firefox extension, I have opened a new tab. I am unaware of how I can write a link to www.google.com and other links (a whole list) in this tab, where the user can click a link and this page will open.

Thank you for your help

so far I had typed in :

```
var newTabBrowser2 = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab());
```

Unfortunately this won't work:

```
var newTabBrowser2 = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab());
newdocument=newTabBrowser2.contentDocument.documentElement.textContent;
newdocument.write("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a><br>");
newdocument.write("<a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">yahoo</a><br>");
```

and I've tried this:

```
var newTabBrowser2 = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab());
newTabBrowser2.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML += "<a
```

href=\"http://www.google.com\">google
";

but that only works when I use the debugger

Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear from your question what you want.  Maybe something like:

```
newwindow=window.open();
newdocument=newwindow.document;
newdocument.write("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a><br>");
newdocument.write("<a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">yahoo</a><br>");
newdocument.close();
```

???

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use textContent to add HTML content to a document - you're possibly better off using the DOM to construct the HTML.

How about something like this (untested):

```
var newTabBrowser2 = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab());
newdocument=newTabBrowser2.contentDocument.documentElement;

var link=newdocument.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", "http://www.google.com");
link.textContent="google";
newdocument.appendChild(link);

newdocument.appendChild(newdocument.createElement("br"));

link=newdocument.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", "http://www.yahoo.com");
link.textContent="yahoo";
newdocument.appendChild(link);

newdocument.appendChild(newdocument.createElement("br"));
```

Alternatively, it *may* be possible to just write to the innerHtml of the document element.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the sort of thing you're looking for.

http://mesh.typepad.com/blog/2004/11/creating_a_new_.html

```
var myUrl = "http://mesh.typepad.com";
var tBrowser = document.getElementById("content");
var tab = tBrowser.addTab(myUrl);
```

This creates a new tab every time it's run - you can update the url of a pre-existing tab like this:

```
var uri = "http://mesh.typepad.com";
tBrowser.getBrowserForTab(tab).loadURI(uri);
```

Finally, you should be able to set the focus to the new tab:

```
tBrowser.selectedTab = tab;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply
I am more concerned with displaying a whole list of links onto a tab and the user chooses one of these